# C# Parsing Return Data into JSON

Tags: c#, sql, json, serialization, boolean

I am having some problem when trying to parse the return data into JSON in C#. So basically I have an example which is in SELECT SQL statement:

```
[WebMethod]
public string getUserDetails(string userID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnStr"].ConnectionString);
    string select = "select * from dbo.User WHERE userID = '" + userID + "'";
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, sqlConnection);
    da.Fill(dt);
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    sqlConnection.Close();
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

These codes works properly. But when it comes to INSERT SQL statement, I not sure how to pass the returning boolean into JSON:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool addUser(UserModel um)
{
    bool result = false;
    result = Conversion.intToBool(SplashAwardsDB.executeNonQuery(
            "INSERT INTO dbo.User ("
            + "userName, password, firstName, lastName, address, contactNo, birthDate, familyID, familyRole, x, y ) "
            + " VALUES ("
            + "'" + um.userName + "', "
            + "'" + um.password + "', "
            + "'" + um.firstName + "', "
            + "'" + um.lastName + "', "
            + "'" + um.address + "', "
            + "'" + um.contactNo + "', "
            + "'" + um.birthDate + "', "
            + "'" + um.familyID + "', "
            + "'" + um.familyRole + "', "
            + "'" + um.x + "', "
            + "'" + um.y + "')"
            ));
        return result;
    }
```

Any guides on how to serialize it?

**EDIT**

```
[WebMethod]
public string checkLoginCredential(string userName, string password)
{
    bool result = false;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SplashAwardsDB.connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT userName, password FROM dbo.User WHERE userName = '" + userName + "' AND password = '" + password + "'", connection);
        connection.Open();
        using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Session["userName"] = dr["userName"];
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }            
    return serializer.Serialize(result);
}
```

basically I am trying to check for login credential. If the username and password match, I will store the userName into sesssion. So how should I modify this so that when my friend call this method, it will return the session data?

Comment: Before you go any further, please please please Google "SQL injection"

Comment: Okay but how should I do this because I tried with this: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(result); but it throws me an error message which is Cannot implicitly convert string to bool

Comment: Well that's because the return type of `addUser` is bool and you are trying to return a string...

Comment: But I have to return it as boolean tho. Just that I need to parse the return data into JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: @IWasSoLost a JSON is a String, a bool is a 0/1 flag; your return type can't be both at the same time. You need to make a design decision before anyone can help you.

Comment: @decPL Okay sure thanks a lot! But would you mind to help me take a look another problem at my edited portion?

Comment: For the love of God... Don't store passwords in plain text. You have already shown that you're vulnerable to SQL injection so it will take all of 30 seconds for someone to slurp all your user's credentials.

Comment: @RobH Okay sure thanks for advice! I will fix that later on. But firstly, I would like to know how to return session data as JSON as my edited portion. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @IWasSoLost at glance, your edited part looks like it should be working. What's your problem with it?

Comment: `return string.Format("{{ \"result\":\"{0}\" }}", result);`

Comment: @decPL Yeah, it's without red lines now but I not sure if I do in this way, when my friend call this method, will he able to get the session data instead of just a boolean?

Comment: @RobH Sorry but what does this part of code do: string.Format("{{ \"result\":\"{0}\" }}" ?

Comment: @IWasSoLost Why don't you simply try? Do you honestly believe it's easier for someone else to find this out for you?

Comment: @decPL okay sure thanks a lot! I could not test it because currently I am in charge of the web service part only and he will do all the logic parts. Still, thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection aside, try using the Newtonsoft JSON library (also called JSON.Net) - available from Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio.  Your JSON can't return just the boolean, otherwise it's not JSON.  Your boolean is a value, which is stored against a field name.  So for instance you would return this:

```
{
  result:true
}
```

The easiest way to do this is to use the following code, which creates an anonymous object and then serializes it as a JSON string:

```
var res = new
{
    result = myResult
};
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
return x;
```

In this case myResult is a boolean variable storing the value you want to return.  This can be shortened to:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { result = myResult });
```

This will return a JSON string, but if you're returning from a web service GET request, you may also want to consider returning a return type of `Stream` instead with the correct mime type, like so:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/json";
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
sw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { result = myResult }));
sw.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
return ms;
```

One benefit of the latter approach is that the JSON string won't be surrounded in quotes, which it is when you return a string.  This isn't a big deal for your example, but any JSON string that has string properties would have the quotes escaped.  Returning as a stream is less of a pain because you won't have to unescape the string before using it.